# How to get data from database by parameters in yii2?

Tags: php, database, yii2, message

I have 2 database tables:

**user**

`id` | `name`,

**message**

`id` | `sender_id` | `receiver_id`.

How can I generate custom view and get data by `sender_id` and `receiver_id`? I mean when user log in he will see his inbox and outbox messages. Please explain the logic of this. I also will be glad if you will provide code examples because I am newbie in php and yii2. If something is not understandable I will explain more specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are really short on details, but I assume you want to display both incoming and sent messages by matching current user ID (logged in user) with both `receiver_id` and `sender_id` and display them in a gridview.

An approach could be:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $user = Yii::$app->user->identity;

    $searchModel = new MesssageSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    // filter on ownership of either sender or receiver
    $dataProvider
        ->query
        ->andWhere(['receiver_id' => $user->id])
        ->orWhere(['sender_id' => $user->id]);

    $dataProvider->setSort([
        'defaultOrder' => ['created_at' => SORT_DESC],
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

This assumes you have limited access to logged-in users otherwise you need to catch the case when `Yii::$app->user` is `null`.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your answer. You got me right. Can I generate custom views with grids that will contain sent and incoming messages by gii or should I write it manually? Thanks.

Comment: I used CRUD generator to create custom views and added labels of them :          ['label' => 'Incoming letters', 'url' => ['incoming/index']],
                    ['label' => 'Sent letters', 'url' => ['sent/index']],
but when I click on label it says 'page not found 404'. Folders incoming and sent are located in backend/views. Could you advice something? Thanks.